# Difficulties with Button Activation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently having issues with a game I am making for fun. I am quite new to Javascript, HTML, and CSS, hence the code that will be shown will not be very good. Anyway, the issue I am experiencing is the button activation part of my code not functioning. Here is the code (in case there are other errors), and the specific problematic area is highlighted.

```js
//Variables and Other Basic Things

var Specs = ["Basic", "Advanced", "Insane", "Mythical", "Godly"];
var PlayerRanks = ["Begginer Grinder", "Advanced Grinder", "Insane Grinder", "Mythic Grinder", "Godlike Grinder"];
var Random = 1;

//Random Numbers

function RandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

//Player Things

var Player = {
  spec: "Plain",
  rank: "Begginer Grinder",
  points: 1000,
  pointIncreaseAmount: 1,
  timeToIncrease: 10000,
  levelIncrease: function() {
    this.points += this.pointIncreaseAmount
  }
}

//Stats of different specs

function StatChange() {
  if (Player.spec == "Basic") {
    Player.pointIncreaseAmount = 2;
    Player.timeToIncrease = 5000;
  } else if (Player.spec == "Advanced") {
    Player.pointIncreaseAmount = 5;
    Player.timeToIncrease = 4000;
  } else if (Player.spec == "Epic") {
    Player.pointIncreaseAmount = 10;
    Player.timeToIncrease = 3000;
  } else if (Player.spec == "Mythical") {
    Player.pointIncreaseAmount = 25;
    Player.timeToIncrease = 2000;
  } else if (Player.spec == "Godly") {
    Player.pointIncreaseAmount = 50;
    Player.timeToIncrease = 1000;
  }
  document.getElementById("SpecDisplay").innerHTML = "Your current spec is " + Player.spec;
}

function OpenBasicCrate() {
  Random = RandomInt(1, 129);
  if (Random < 75) {
    Player.spec = "Basic";
    Random = 1;
  } else if (Random >= 75 && Random < 120) {
    Player.spec = "Advanced";
    Random = 1;
  } else if (Random >= 120 && Random < 129) {
    Player.spec = "Epic";
    Random = 1;
  }
  StatChange();
}

function OpenBetterCrate() {
  Random = RandomInt(1, 105);
  if (Random < 30) {
    Player.spec = "Basic";
    Random = 1;
  } else if (Random >= 30 && Random < 85) {
    Player.spec = "Advanced";
    Random = 1;
  } else if (Random >= 85 && Random <= 105) {
    Player.spec = "Epic";
    Random = 1;
  }
  StatChange();
}

function OpenAdvancedCrate() {
  Random = RandomInt(1, 80);
  if (Random < 30) {
    Player.spec = "Advanced";
    Random = 1;
  } else if (Random >= 30 && Random <= 70) {
    Player.spec = "Epic";
    Random = 1;
  } else if (Random >= 70 && Random < 80) {
    PLayer.spec = "Mythical";
    Random = 1;
  }
  StatChange();
}

function OpenBetterAdvancedCrate() {
  Random = RandomInt(1, 85);
  if (Random < 80) {
    Player.spec = "Mythical";
    Random = 1;
  } else if (Random >= 80 && Random <= 85) {
    Player.spec = "Epic";
    Random = 1;
  }
  StatChange();
}

function OpenMythicalCrate() {
  Random = RandomInt(1, 100);
  if (Random < 95) {
    Player.spec = "Mythical";
    Random = 1;
  } else if (Random >= 95 && Random < 100) {
    Player.spec = "Godly";
    Random = 1;
  }
}

//Start Command also Repeating Code

function Start() {
  const pointGain = setInterval(function() {
    Player.levelIncrease()
  }, Player.timeToIncrease);
  const alertPoints = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = "Score: " + Player.points
  }, 101);
}

//Checking button clicks

if (document.getElementById('Start').clicked == true) {
  Start(); //Start button
}

//Checking crates and if the buttons are pressed

//HERE

if (document.getElementById("OpenCrateA").clicked == true) {
  if (Player.points >= 50) {
    OpenBasicCrate();
    Player.points -= 50;
  } else if (Player.points < 50) {
    document.getElementById("DisplayError").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("DisplayError").style.display = "none";
    }, 3000);
  }
}

if (document.getElementById("OpenCrateB").clicked == true) {
  if (Player.points >= 125) {
    OpenBetterCrate();
    Player.points -= 125;
  } else if (Player.points < 125) {
    document.getElementById("DisplayError").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("DisplayError").style.display = "none";
    }, 3000); // Come back here later
  }
}

if (document.getElementById("OpenCrateC").clicked == true) {
  if (Player.points >= 300) {
    OpenAdvancedCrate();
    Player.points -= 300;
  } else if (Player.points < 300) {
    document.getElementById("DisplayError").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("DisplayError").style.display = "none";
    }, 3000);
  }
}

if (document.getElementById("OpenCrateD").clicked == true) {
  if (Player.points >= 1500) {
    OpenBetterAdvancedCrate();
    Player.points -= 1500;
  } else if (Player.points < 1500) {
    document.getElementById("DisplayError").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("DisplayError").style.display = "none";
    }, 3000);
  }
}

if (document.getElementById("OpenCrateE").clicked == true) {
  if (Player.points >= 15000) {
    OpenMythicalCrate();
    Player.points -= 15000;
  } else if (Player.points < 15000) {
    document.getElementById("DisplayError").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("DisplayError").style.display = "none";
    }, 3000);
  }
}

//TO HERE
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/656847228219949067/855371548860350474/backgroundImage.png);
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 375px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  outline: 3px dotted black;
}

.OpenCrateA {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/656847228219949067/855379404020121620/backgroundImage.png);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 425px;
  left: 5px;
  outline: 2px solid black;
}

.OpenCrateB {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/656847228219949067/855379943093829642/backgroundImage.png);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 425px;
  left: 110px;
  outline: 2px solid black;
}

.OpenCrateC {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/656847228219949067/855379735671865344/backgroundImage.png);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 425px;
  left: 215px;
  outline: 2px solid black;
}

.OpenCrateD {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/656847228219949067/855380083225526282/backgroundImage.png);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 425px;
  left: 320px;
  outline: 2px solid black;
}

.OpenCrateE {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/656847228219949067/855380283788492810/backgroundImage.png);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 425px;
  left: 425px;
  outline: 2px solid black;
}

.Start {
  width: 100;
  height: 30;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
  background-color: red;
  outline: 2px solid black;
}

.InstructionMenu {
  background-color: blue;
  outline: 2px solid black
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
}

.RankDisplay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 375px;
  background-color: blue;
  outline: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>

<h1 id="welcomingScreen">Welcome to "A Bad Grinding Game!"</h1>

<button id="StartButton" class="Start" onclick="Start()">Start</button>

<p id="Score"> Score: </p>

<p id="RankDisplay" class="RankDisplay"> Your current rank is: "Begginer Grinder"</p>

<p id="SpecDisplay" class="SpecDisplay"> Your current spec is "Plain"</p>

<h2 id="InstructionsMenu" class="InstructionMenu" style="display:none">Instrutions:</h2>

<p id="InstructionsMenu" class="InstructionMenu" style="display:none"> This is a simple grinding game. You have a "spec", which allows you to gain a specific amount of "points" per a specific amount of time. The longer you grind, the better your rank becomes, and a better rank gives a slight point increase. </p>

<p id="DisplayError" style="display:none"> You do not have enough money to purchase this crate!</p>

<img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/656847228219949067/855161969615175680/ABGG_icon.png"></img>

<button type="button" class="OpenCrateA" id="OpenCrateA">Open Crate 1</p>

<button type="button" class="OpenCrateB" id="OpenCrateB">Open Crate 2 </button>

<button type="button" class="OpenCrateC" id="OpenCrateC">Open Crate 3 </button>

<button type="button" class="OpenCrateD" id="OpenCrateD">Open Crate 4 </button>

<button type="button" class="OpenCrateE" id="OpenCrateE">Open Crate 5 </button>
```

[image: An Image of the Game]

Comment: 1. you put `<script src="script.js">` before the HTML, so the script runs before any HTML element exists. Therefore `getElementById("OpenCrateA")` returns `null`, which explains the error in the console : `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clicked' of null"`. Place `<script src="script.js">` just before `</body>`. 2. `getElementById("OpenCrateA").clicked == true` is not how you trigger a function on button click :) [addEventListener() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)

Comment: Also, you seem to mix up class and id sometimes for your elements. For example document.getElementById('Start') won't find anything because your start button has the id "StartButton" and not "Start". 
The CSS for it will work since it has the right class, though.
Fair warning, having an element id with the exact same name as a function will sometimes mess up javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button activation logic is not working because you're checking if `button.clicked == true`. As far as I am aware, button HTML events don't even have a `clicked` property.

Even if they did, while you are indeed correct that that would check if a button is pressed, it would only so once, right when the user first loads the page, so any subsequent presses would be ignored.

The method you are looking for is `button.onclick`, which you can [read about here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick). With it, your code would look something like:

```
document.getElementById("OpenCrateA").onclick = function(){
  if (Player.points >= 50){
    OpenBasicCrate();
    Player.points -= 50;
  }
  else if (Player.points < 50){
    document.getElementById("DisplayError").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("DisplayError").style.display = "none"; }, 3000); 
  }
}
```

This registers a *listener* for the button's click event, which will trigger whenever the button is pressed and call the logic that you define.

Another issue you may face is that the button element you are trying to select is not defined. This would occur due to your `<script>` tag being at the top of your HTML, so it runs before any of your HTML is even rendered. I would suggest moving it to the bottom of your HTML `<body>`